# Getting blocked from crawling data from website in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler, data-science

I am new to web scraping and building crawlers and i started practicing on a grocery website.

I've been trying to crawl data from a website for quite some time and could'nt get through for more than three pages, for the first three pages the websites let's me access the data but after that i dont get any response and even for a few seconds i stop getting response on the browser as well. The website uses API to get all the data so i can not even use BeautifulSoup, i thought of using selenium but no luck there too.
I am using python's requests library to get the data and json to parse. The website requires post method to access all the products so i am sending cookies, headers and params as well and using same cookies etc for the next pages also.

I am looking for some general responses if anyone went through the same situation and got a workaround maybe.

Thank you.

Comment: use a user-agent

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow we answer specific questions about programming. Questions asking for general advise are typically considered too unclear or too broad.

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese I have tried using multiple user-agent s but still the same problem persists

Comment: give us the link

Comment: The link is: https://www.kroger.com/pl/fresh-fruits-vegetables/06
I want to get data from all the pages and i succeed for only the first few

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can unblock this website. (Sorry, can't provide the code because, it is likely to not fucntion without my location details. So try the method I say to get the code).

1. Open that link in Google Chrome > Open Developer Tools by pressing Ctrl + Shift + I > Go to Networks tab. Over there, go to XMR and find 'details'. This looks like:

[image]

1. Right click on it, Copy it as Bash Curl.
2. Go to [Curl to Requests](https://curl.trillworks.com/) , paste the code, and press enter. The curl gets converted to requests. Copy that and run.
3. Here in that, the last line will be like:

```
response = requests.post('https://www.kroger.com/products/api/products/details', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

This does the requests.
 4. Now after this, when we extract what we require:

```
data = response.json() # saving as a dictionary

product = data['products'] # getting the product
```

5. Now from this scraped data, take whatever you need. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for going through all the trouble but as i said i was able to get all the data but only for the first three pages,  This only provides details of 24 products as given in data parameters but to get the data values i had to run the search api first and extract 'upcs' values and then pass them to data variable. As i did try all of this before and it worked but only for the first few pages and not for the rest of them so i want to know if there's a trick to bypass this whole situation and get all the products. If you have any solutions for this you are welcome to share :)